# What does the `--fresh` option do in Brew?

Tags: command-line, homebrew, caffe

While following installation instructions (e.g., for [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_osx.html) for os x), I run into the `--fresh` flag for [homebrew](http://brew.sh/). For example,

```
brew install --fresh -vd snappy leveldb gflags glog szip lmdb
```

However, I see no documentation about what `--fresh` does, and I don't find it in the source code for homebrew. What does this flag do? (Or what did it used to do?)

Comment: don't you want your coffee `fresh`? ;)

Comment: I think you're on to something. I replaced `--fresh` with `--pre-ground` and got the same results. Only didn't taste as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an old [github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/26979) describing the behavior of `--fresh`.

The flag was meant to ensure packages would be installed without any previously set compile-time options (like `--with-python`), but it was removed because it didn't do anything:

```
commit 64744646e9be93dd758ca5cf202c6605accf4deb
Author: Jack Nagel <jacknagel@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Jul 5 19:28:15 2014 -0500

    Remove remaining references to "--fresh"

    This option was removed in 8cdf4d8ebf439eb9a9ffcaa0e455ced9459e1e41
    because it did not do anything.
```